# How to reset HTML5 form validation errors when click back button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, requiredfieldvalidator

Im having an issue clearing the HTML5 oninvalid red border around inputs. If a user clicks the submit button without correctly filling out the form, the HTML5 setCustomValidity errors will show and the default red outline will appear around any required input fields that were left blank...this all works great. Problem is, if a user clicks the back button, then comes back to this form or another section of the form within this form, the form will still display all invalid form elements with the red outline.

What i would like to happen, is if this forms "go back" button is clicked, that will reset/clear the form so that all form elements are reset and none will display the red outline unless the form was once again submitted and has empty/incorrect form information.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
<form class="login-form" aria-label="Login" action="" method="post">
  <div class="login-A">
    <h4>Are you a client?</h4>
    <div>
       <button class="lx-button lx-button--small lx-button--primary" id="client-yes" type=button>
         Yes
       </button>
       <button class="lx-button lx-button--small lx-button--primary" id="client-no" type=button>
         No
       </button>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="login-B">
      <h4>Existing client information</h4>
      <button class="lx-button lx-button--small lx-button--tertiary back" id="olb-back-btn-2" type=button>
         Go back
      </button>
      <p>Enter your online ID and Password</p>
      <div>
        <div>
           <label for="olb-user-id">User ID</label>
           <input id="olb-user-id" name="olbuserid" maxlength="20" type="text" required="required" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('User ID is required.')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
        </div>
        <div>
           <label for="olb-password">Password</label>
           <input id="olb-password" name="olbpassword" maxlength="28" value="" type="password" required="required" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Password is required.')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="lx-button lx-button--small lx-button--primary" id="login-button" type=submit>
         Continue
      </button>
   </div><!-- login-B -->
   <div class="login-C">
       <h4 class="text">New client</h4>
       <button class="lx-button lx-button--small lx-button--tertiary back" id="olb-back-btn-3" type=button>
          Go back
       </button>
       <label for="login-state">Select your state to view your account options.</label>
       <div class="login-state-container">
           <select id="login-state" name="login-state" required="required" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('State is required.')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
               <option value="" selected="selected">State</option>
               <option value="AL">AL</option>
               <option value="FL">FL</option>
               <option value="GA">GA</option>
               <option value="IN">IN</option>
               <option value="WV">WV</option>
               <option value="DC">Washington, DC</option>
           </select>
       </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Ive searched for days trying to figure out how to solve this issue. I have tried:

```
function clearValidity(){
    document.getElementById('olb-user-id').setCustomValidity('');
    document.getElementById('olb-password').setCustomValidity('');
    document.getElementById('login-state').setCustomValidity('');
}

document.getElementById( 'olb-back-btn-2' ).onclick = function()  {clearValidity()};
document.getElementById( 'olb-back-btn-3' ).onclick = function()  {clearValidity()};
```

also tried:

```
$('.login-form').trigger("reset");
```

Along with many other trials from posts i have read but nothing seems to work. Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The back button is a save of how the last page ended. The only way to do this, is to change the form to post the data using Javascript.

Use javascript collect the data and HttpXML to post it

1. First collect the data with JavaScript
2. Then clear all the fields using javascript
3. Post the data using javascript a HttpXML request
4. Upon return (xml repsonse) Redirect if required or show an error for them to re complete the form (the form will now be blank and ready to start again)

If using this method be sure to disable the submit button until the response has been returned from the XML post to stop the user submitting multiple times

Comment: when i say "back button" it is not the browsers back button, but a back button in my form. Im not saving form information nor do i want to on clicking the forms back button.

Comment: if you have a back button on your form just use an onclick, then document.getElementById('test').value = " "; this will clear the form ready for re use

Comment: That doesnt work to reset HTML5 native form fields that are required. it doesnt reset the invalid red border on fields that are empty or invalid

Comment: Try enclosing the whole form in javascript then deleting it and putting it back. Use a dive to wrap the whole form. e.g. var document.getElementById(formwrap).innerHTML = ""; document.getElementById(formwrap).innerHTML = "<form> ... </form>